# Import .dmp file failed in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

In oracle 11 g ,  I try to import .dmp file to oracle , I get the following error.

```
C:\Users\user>impdp system/********@devf02 dumpfile=FEED.dmp logfile=FEED.l
og schemas=FEED

Import: Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production on Wednesday, 05 March, 2014 9:00:10

Copyright (c) 2003, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Produc
tion
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-31694: master table "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01" failed to load/unload
ORA-02354: error in exporting/importing data
ORA-02373: Error parsing insert statement for table "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_
01".
ORA-00904: "ORIGINAL_OBJECT_NAME": invalid identifier
```

How to solve it. When I check table as SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01 , it has 90 column. My friend's SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01 table has 91 column. Difference column name is ORIGINAL_OBJECT_NAME. This column name no has my table.

Comment: From which version did you take the import of the schema, is it same `11.1.0.6.0`?

Comment: @Dba , may be version 11.1.0.6.0

Comment: Does sound like you've used a different version for the export and import operations.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs due to an inconsistency in the dump file.  This occurs typically during transfer of the file from server to server or across operating systems.

You can export new dump file, and before starting to transfer, zip it using gzip or any other command.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35493652)